# Getting the number of steps from heath kit and use the app

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, healthkit

I am trying to build an app that collecting daily step data even my app is at background or inactive. So the best way is to get the data directly from the accelerate meter or health kit. 
My question is, is there any code that i can obtain these data? 
Thanks